# Wi-Fi disconnects very often

Tags: wifi

I have laptop "Lenovo s110" with Fedora 22. Wi-Fi randomly disconnects and can't autoconnect.

```
$ dmesg
...
[15066.713308] wlp2s0: authenticate with 78:44:76:58:69:ef
[15066.742924] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 1/3)
[15066.844039] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 2/3)
[15066.945045] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 3/3)
[15067.046071] wlp2s0: authentication with 78:44:76:58:69:ef timed out
[15068.554725] wlp2s0: authenticate with 78:44:76:58:69:ef
[15068.585268] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 1/3)
[15068.686190] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 2/3)
[15068.787205] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 3/3)
[15068.888242] wlp2s0: authentication with 78:44:76:58:69:ef timed out
[15070.831181] wlp2s0: authenticate with 78:44:76:58:69:ef
[15070.864327] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 1/3)
[15070.965439] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 2/3)
[15071.066467] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 3/3)
[15071.167458] wlp2s0: authentication with 78:44:76:58:69:ef timed out
[15080.948778] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

And when I connect manually (choose my home Wi-Fi network and click "connect") it connects:

```
$ dmesg
...
[15556.678847] wlp2s0: authenticate with 78:44:76:58:69:ef
[15556.695394] wlp2s0: send auth to 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 1/3)
[15556.696906] wlp2s0: authenticated
[15556.698328] wlp2s0: associate with 78:44:76:58:69:ef (try 1/3)
[15556.702316] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 78:44:76:58:69:ef (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[15556.702833] wlp2s0: associated
[15556.702895] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)

I have no idea what to do. Please, give me at least some advice.

Comment: only vague advice (suffering from a lack of circumstantial evidence):  are you absolutely sure that the script which does the automatic connection has the same authentication key/passphrase as you do when you type in the "manual" connection?   if so, i'd next check the signal strength.  i've seen this sort of behavior when the strength dips even a bit below optimum.  otherwise, try this same experiment with another wifi station and see if you get the same behavior (divide and conquer your causes)

Comment: Oh, it seems like I need to spend a huge amount of time on these experiments. If there are no other thoughts, I will.